# Find substring from string in sql

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, t-sql, find, substring

I am using SQL SERVER 2008.I have following string in sql.

```
DECLARE @stringRTF VARCHAR(MAX)

set @stringRTF = '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs18 \v [\TEST\*#70_250_263] \v0 \par '
```

Now i want to find string "\TEST*#" from above string.
if it is present in the full string then i want to cut string [\TEST*#70_250_263] from full string.

So it should be return like

```
[\TEST\*#70_250_263]
```

as return string.

So can any one help me out how to find and cut that string from original string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you use? SQL SERVER 2008?

Comment: @ITBeginner i am using sql server 2008.

Comment: You could use LIKE or REGEXP (as in "WHERE field LIKE '%[\TEST\*#70_250_263]%' or "WHERE field REGEXP 'TEST'") and then actually perform the extraction in code, or you could use PREG_CAPTURE as is shown here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html (if you're using MySQL.  MSSQL might support a REGEXP_SUBSTR like Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @stringRTF VARCHAR(1024)
SELECT @stringRTF = 
    '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs18 \v [\TEST\*#70_250_263] \v0 \par '

DECLARE @res VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @res = SUBSTRING(
    @stringRTF, 
    CHARINDEX('\TEST\*#', @stringRTF) - 1, 
    CHARINDEX(']', @stringRTF) - CHARINDEX('\TEST\*#', @stringRTF) + 2 
)

PRINT @res
```

Output:

```
[\TEST\*#70_250_263]
```

@ITBeginner, change this rows in your code:

```
'\TEST*#' to '\TEST\*#'
@stringRTF.length to LEN(@stringRTF)
```

Comment: Nice one. My answer have don't know what's the problem.

Comment: @ITBeginner, happy to help you. To make to make fewer syntax errors try to use any auto-completion toolsб like this: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/

Answer (score 2):

I think below code should work:

```
DECLARE @stringRTF VARCHAR(1000), @stringFind VARCHAR(30), @startIndex 

int,@outputString varchar(100)

set @stringRTF = '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs18 \v [\TEST\*#70_250_263] \v0 \par '

SET @stringFind = '\TEST\*#'
SET @startIndex =  CHARINDEX(@stringFind, @stringRTF) - 1
SET @outputString = SUBSTRING(@stringRTF , @startIndex,  len(@stringRTF))
SET @outputString = LEFT(@outputString , CHARINDEX(']',@outputString) )
PRINT @outputString --Your result
```

Tell me if you face any error.